# Workflow design in AWS Ec2 instances not involving lambda

Tags: amazon-ec2, workflow, amazon-swf, aws-step-functions

Thanks in advance for your time and answers.

- I have multiple, say 3 AWS EC2 windows instances.
- I have .NET executables A, B and C in each of the 3 windows instances. (I could also have java programs in the mix)
- They need to be run, one after the other, in a workflow like fashion, depending on the outcome of the previous executable. i.e B should run after A has succeeded; C should run after B has succeeded etc. In short, I am looking to
  achieve a work flow.
- Being in the AWS, I looked at Amazon Simple Workflow;  however to me
  to use that, I need to weave in the AWS SWS SDK in the .NET code. But
  unfortunately I only have the executable and am not allowed to
  rebuild that.
- I also have the Amazon Simple Queue Service and notification service in
  mind.

  **But is there a better and preferred way to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a better and preferred way to achieve this ?

Yes. The preferred way nowadays is to use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) which is (sort of) an improved, simplified and clean version of Amazon Simple Workflow. Since you have a precompiled executables running in a sequential order it might be worth it to also take a look at [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/).

Step Functions are basically Lambda functions, but you can ship you executables with the deployment package and execute them from Lambda functions.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Sergey. I didn't know about the AWS Step functions and on investigating it, seem to be the best solution. I can add activities which can be associated with my executables running on the EC2 instance. I will implement the solution and provide the details in here for the benefit of other.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer supplied by Sergey, I implemented the Step Function and it works great.
I am posting this as a follow up to provide further details on how I implemented this.

1) Created an AWS state machine with a sequence of Activities, from the AWS console using JSON DSL.
   (There are several posts which explain how to create a state machines)

2) My State machine should start the work flow based on a file upload to a particular directory.

3) So, I wrote a java application (could be c# or anything), which would

- use a file watcher to kick off the AWS workflow.

  ```
  import com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.AWSStepFunctions;
  import com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder;
  import com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.StartExecutionRequest;

  class StepFunctionExecution {
  private StartExecutionRequest startExecutionRequest = new StartExecutionRequest();
  public void Start(String filePath){
      final AWSStepFunctions client = AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder
              .standard()
              .build();

      /** Start execution */
      startExecutionRequest.setStateMachineArn("MyARN");
      startExecutionRequest.setName(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      String inputJson = "{\r\n  \"FilePath\": \"" + filePath + "\"\r\n}";
      startExecutionRequest.setInput(inputJson);
      client.startExecution(startExecutionRequest);
      }
  }
  ```

4) I started another thread in the same java application (I could as well use a separate java application)

- which continously monitors the first activity in the AWS step function.

  ```
      final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
  clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(65));
  final AWSStepFunctions client = AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder
          .standard()
          .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
          .build();

  while (true) {
      GetActivityTaskResult getActivityTaskResult =
              client.getActivityTask(
                      new GetActivityTaskRequest().withActivityArn("myArn"));
      if (getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken() != null) {
          try {
                  // Do actual processing
                  client.sendTaskSuccess(
                          new SendTaskSuccessRequest()
                                  .withOutput("{}")
                                  .withTaskToken(getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken()));
          } catch (final Exception e) {
              client.sendTaskFailure(
                      new SendTaskFailureRequest()
                              .withCause(e.getMessage())
                              .withTaskToken(getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken()));
          }
      } else {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

5) I ran these Java executables, right inside of the AWS EC2 instance.

The EC2 instances were assigned the IAM role to access the Step function resources etc.

So, there was no need of separate credentials to access the Step functions and activities.